# Check if query run successfully through python

Tags: python, mysql, bash

I have a .sql script that contain all mysql queries. Now suppose after executing the script I want to check if the queries run successfully or not. In command line if we do

```
echo $?
```

Then it will return 0 if query is success and 1 if its not successful.

No I want to do it in python Script. How can this be done ?

My python script :

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='myuser', password='mypass', host='127.1.2.3', database='mydb')
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.executescript("sql_queries.sql")
    cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about having python returning an exit code after running your script?  You want to read up on [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

In your example you might have something like

```
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    ...
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    # Might want to check whether the executescript was successful
    try:
        cursor.executescript("sql_queries.sql")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit(1)
    cnx.close()
```

Naturally, this has been asked some time ago, and other related questions:

- [Exit codes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285289/exit-codes-in-python)
- [Exit code when python script has unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456157/exit-code-when-python-script-has-unhandled-exception)
- [Setting exit code in Python when an exception is raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720119/setting-exit-code-in-python-when-an-exception-is-raised)

Also do consider sending the error messages out to stderr instead of leaving the default `print()` to stdout, see:

- [How to print to stderr in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python)

Comment: I want to check for a particular query in my .sql file. Say i want to check if certain insertion is made properly or not'

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014233/how-do-i-check-if-an-insert-was-successful-with-mysqldb-in-python